# AVPlayer not loading video in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, avplayer

```
AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
playerViewController.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                                       URLForResource:@"Besan"
                                                       withExtension:@"mp4"]];
[playerViewController.player play];
```

I am trying to use the AVPlayerViewController in iOS 8. But the video does not load. I simply get the screen below.

The entire codebase is here https://github.com/sairamsankaran/AVPlayerDemo

[image]

Comment: Not sure why you didn't debug the URL

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I download your project and had a look. The solution is pretty simple, you forgot to include the video file in your target, which means when you're setting up the URL you're pointing to a file that doesn't exist, which means the `NSURL` is nil.

In the Utilities side bar in Xcode, with your mp4 file chosen in the navigator, choose the File Inspector and in "Target Membership" be sure to check your app target.

[image]

Once you have done this your movie will play on launch.

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off starting with a working example and extending that. If you like, you can try a working xcode example project that uses AVPlayerViewController in github described in my [blog post](http://www.modejong.com/blog/post13_iOS8_SunSpot/index.html), this is an example project that shows a high def SDO video of the Sun, it looks best on a newish retina iPad since the video is very high quality.

Answer (score 0):

@runmad, i also done with the same way,but i'm trying to open local video.here is my code

```
{
// Initialize the movie player view controller with a video URL string
        AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
        /*NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qcI2_v7Vj2U"];
         playerViewController.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];*/
//        playerViewController.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL: [ [filePath]URLForResource:@"Besan"
//                                                                withExtension:@"mp4"]];
        NSLog(@"\nFile URL\n%@",videosURL);
        AVPlayerItem* item=[[AVPlayerItem alloc]initWithURL:videosURL];
        NSLog(@"\n\nAVPlayerItem\n%@",item);
        playerViewController.player=[AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:item];
        [playerViewController.player play];
        [self presentViewController:playerViewController animated:YES completion:^{}];
}
```

i've done without `AVPlayerItem` but the result is same(Only black screen with done,play,forward,backward buttons).

than i tried with `MPMoviePlayerController` but it dismissed soon without displaying video.
here is MPMoviePlayerController Code,

```
{
    MPMoviePlayerViewController   *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:videosURL];
        [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayerController];
        [moviePlayerController.moviePlayer play];
}
```